# What does a negative surface integral mean?

Tags: surface-integrals

My try:
The surface integral could be interpreted as the flux of a fluid, i.e., the amount of fluid flowing through the surface per unit time. So does a negative or positive sign actually mean the direction of the flow?  Or it has something else to mean?

If the sign really denotes the direction of the flow, then is the positive direction always considered to the direction of outward drawn unit normal vector to the surface?

Comment: Yep... direction of flow.

Comment: thanks @DavidG.Stork

Comment: You can have the normal vector going inward or outward (although outward is more common).  Positive means direction of flow is in same direction as normal, and negative means in opposite direction as the normal.